# How can I trigger an event when the device's profile is changed?

Tags: java, android, cyanogenmod

I'd like to trigger an event when the user changes the phone's profile but I'm not sure how. Idealy, I could catch the a broadcast intent and know when the profile has changed but I haven't been able to find any documentation on this.

If I'm correct, the profile system is not a part of the stock AOSP but Cyanogenmod.

I've trudged through the only two profile-related classes I could find:

- https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-10.1/core/java/android/app/ProfileManager.java
- https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-10.1/core/java/android/app/Profile.java

The only broadcast intent that I could find was [here](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-10.1/core/java/android/app/ProfileManager.java#L121).

Any idea on how this could be accomplished? My application only targets devices running Cyanogenmod 10.1. This is the profile manager from CyanogenMod to give you a clearer idea of what I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: maybe you can create background service, that every 10 seconds check if the current profile is the same as the saved one.

Comment: Polling is always an option but I was looking for something on the lines of a callback or an intent that might be buried in the sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my discussions with the Cyanogenmod developers, it can be handled by added a `BroadcastReceiver` for the `Intent` in [`ProfileManagerService.java`](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-10.1/services/java/com/android/server/ProfileManagerService.java#L63)

The issue was that this intent was missing from the `ProfileManager.java` class and instead existed elsewhere.

The issue for this question can be found on [Cyanogenmod's issue tracker](https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/CYAN-1721).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether i am right about what you want,but in my case it works good.Try if it can help you.
I used here **2 buttons** to set profile as **silent** and **default** mode.Trigger your events when those will activate upon button click.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

    Button silent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.silent);
    Button default = (Button) findViewById(R.id.default);

    final AudioManager mode = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    silent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            text.setText("The Mobile in Silent Mode"); //i use example case,trigger your event here

            mode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Silent Mode Activated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
     });

    default.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            text.setText("The Mobile in Default Mode"); //trigger your event here

            mode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Default Mode Activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
     });
 }
```

Apparently this can also help you..

- [how can I detect whether the android phone in Silent mode programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048427/how-can-i-detect-whether-the-android-phone-in-silent-mode-programatically)
- [How to make android phone silent in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360815/how-to-make-android-phone-silent-in-java?rq=1)
- [How to find whether phone is in sleep/idle mode for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691727/how-to-find-whether-phone-is-in-sleep-idle-mode-for-android?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Since those are two separate environments, I don't think it is possible right now to detect when you switch from one to the other.

Comment: please look at my edited question. I've added more information on what I mean by "Profile". I was talking about the system profile and not the user profile.

Comment: In that case that's indeed very different. That's a cyanogen only feature right ? In that case you should maybe move your question there and maybe open a feature request (or even better, a pull request).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I trigger an event when the device's profile is changed?

Android does not have any support for this , in other words **you can not trigger some event while change the profile .**

you can only trigger event when device Ringer mode has change but not for the profile .

even i could not find the profile names of devices and current set profile name which could be the way  to make what you are searching for .